# WrapPanel not wrapping when in a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, stackpanel, wrappanel

The labels in the example below (WPF/XAML) just parade off the screen, no wrapping occurs.  Removing the orientation works, but doesn't provided the needed functionality/look & feel.  Any ideas how to make the `WrapPanel` wrap to the current size of the `StackPanel`?

```
<Window Height="300" Width="600">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Label Height="28" Name="label1" Width="120">First Name</Label>
            <Label Height="28" Name="label2" Width="120">John</Label>
            <Label Height="28" Name="label3" Width="120">Last Name</Label>
            <Label Height="28" Name="label4" Width="120">Smith</Label>
            <!-- ...more labels!... -->
        </WrapPanel>
        <!-- ...other controls/panels... -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can bind the `WrapPanel`'s `MaxWidth` to the `StackPanel`'s `ActualWidth`.

I haven't tried this, but basically:

`<WrapPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myStackPanel}"/>`

Comment: That seems to work; thanks! The problem is there are other things in the stackpanel and their widths are not taken into account.  Any ideas for handling that?

Comment: Maybe you should use a grid or DockPanel instead?  Or you could use a multibinding and a binding converter to do some custom logic.

Comment: 13 years later, thank you. This helped me today and yeah, it worked. :D

Answer (score 9):

What you're doing isn't possible because of the algorithm that `StackPanel` uses when doing horizontal layout. It's basically going to ask each child element how big it wants to be and however much space it asks for it's going to give it.

You would either need to:

1. Set a `Width` or `MaxWidth` on the `WrapPanel`.
2. Use a `WrapPanel` as the outer panel in place of the `StackPanel`.